# python dictionary with list values to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

Trying to convert a python dict that has:

- nteger keys
- length 4 integer lists as values

  {38.0: [139.0, 1.8, 36.0, 18.2], etc}

into a numpy array, for analysis with sci-kit learn bayesian ridge regression.

Comment: define "convert" - what is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: What sort of array? Do you want an array with n rows and 5 columns, n rows and 4 columns, etc.? should the array just be rows of the lists in the dictionary or something else?

Comment: Normal input to `array` is a list, or list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean what I think you mean this is a simple way to do it (it's a bit shorter to use append but for large arrays always preallocate using numpy).

```
    myDict = {38.0: [139.0, 1.8, 36.0, 18.2], 39.0: [139.0, 1.8, 36.0, 18.2]}
    y = np.zeros(len(myDict))
    X = np.zeros((len(myDict), 4))
    i = 0
    for key, values in myDict.iteritems():
        y[i] = key
        X[i, :] = values
        i += 1
```